# Compute $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5^n}{5^n + 3^n} $

Tags: calculus

How can I compute the next limit of sequences:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5^n}{5^n + 3^n} $$

It is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ indeterminate when evaluating in $n$, but using L'Hopital never eliminates the $5^n, 3^n$ terms. But because the denominator is greater than the numerator, it seems that the limit should be 1 or zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5^n}{5^n + 3^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5^n}{5^n\left(1 + \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n} = 1,$$

since $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{5^n}{5^n+3^n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n}=1$$